# Cannot get id of dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a webpage that will dynamically generate a number of inputs via ajax.  I would like to retrieve the id (and ultimatly the new value) of any input that is changed.  Below is a very simple example of my site.  Right now I'm using delegate to attach an event handler to retrieve the id and new value of the input, but I cannot get the values I want.  Is my implementation incorrect?  I'm new to jquery so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <form id="test_form">
            <input type="submit">
      </form>

      <div id="inputs">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/loader.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    $("#test_form").submit(function() {
        // this variable is just an example, the actual variable will be
        // returned via ajax and will have 1-20 inputs
        var inputs = {
            input1: "default1",
            input2: "default2"
        }

        for (var key in inputs) {
            var li = $("<li>")
            var input = $("<input>")
            input.attr({
                type: "text",
                value: inputs[key],
                id: "id_" + key
            })
            li.append(input)
            $("#inputs").append(li)
            input.onchange
        }

        return false; // stop the form from submitting
    });

    var onChangeFunction = function(){
       // does not show id of the input the text was changed on
       alert($(this).id)
       alert($(this).value)
    }

    $("#inputs").delegate("input", "change", onChangeFunction)


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A) Use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()` and B) you have the argument order wrong. `$("#inputs").on("change", "input", onChangeFunction)`

Comment: To clarify @j08691's comment, your current argument order for [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is correct, but if you follow his suggestion to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (which I would also suggest), you'll need to switch the first two arguments as explained above.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm stuck using jquery 1.11 for this project so I was under the impression I would have to use delegate instead of on.  I'll look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects do not have an `id` property or `value` property. You need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the DOM attributes of the elements like `id` (or sometimes [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)), and you can use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to read the `value` property:

```
alert($(this).attr("id"))
alert($(this).val())
```